# Using ArrayHelper in view file in Yii2

Tags: yii2, helper, yii2-advanced-app

I am trying to use `ArrayHelper` in `Yii2 advanced template project` and it says Class `ArrayHelper` not found. I added `use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper`  and it works in controller. But this problem continue to happen when I use `ArrayHelper` in view file.  How can I autoload these classes in `Yii2`.

Comment: Please tell us what have you attempted so far. Refer [here on how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: please explain your question deeply??

Comment: Can you please add your code sample.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

make sure you add namespace in view file too.

```
//in view_file_name.php
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
```

Answer (score 0):

You Did not show the code . So i am not able to give you the exact answer:
But you ask that you want to use array helper in your view so try this:
it is working .

```
use app\models\User;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
   //use app\models\user;
$user=User::find()->all();
//use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
$listData=ArrayHelper::map($user,'user_id','username');

echo '<pre>';
print_r($listData);
echo '</pre>';
```

for more details  visit :[Yii2 Docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-helper-array.html)